# Google maps apiv3 'click' and 'dragend' single listener

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

working on my code to retrieve lat,long by clicking and it works fine. wondering if its possible to combine 'click' and 'dragend' in a single event listener if not. Would appreciate whats a proper alternative.

This is what I've been working on.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map,'click', function(event) {
    document.getElementById("latbox").value = event.latLng.lat();
    document.getElementById("lngbox").value = event.latLng.lng();
    addMarker(event.latLng);
  });
}

 function addMarker(location) {

if (!marker) {

    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map,
    draggable:true,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
}
// Otherwise, simply update its location on the map.
else { marker.setPosition(location); }
 }
```

I tried doing this `google.maps.event.addListener(map,'click','dragend', function(event)` but to no avail. also if anyone has an idea to modify this `marker.setPosition(location);` to have `animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP` . . thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no built-in method to apply a listener for multiple events.

When your problem is that you don't want to define the callback-function twice, you may either use a non-anonymous function or define the listener for 1 event and trigger the event when the other event fires:

```
google.maps.event.addListener( map, 'click',
                              function(e){ alert('clicked or dragged');} );
google.maps.event.addListener( map, 'dragend', function(){
                              google.maps.event.trigger(this, 'click');} );
```

Related to the animation:
Instead of using the marker-methods(setAnimation,setPosition) to set marker-options, you also may use the method setOptions to set multiple options at once:

```
marker.setOptions({ position  : location,
                    animation : google.maps.Animation.DROP});
```

Comment: Thanks You have been of great help. Will use those techniques.